# Incorrect transparent texture rendering in cycles

Tags: texturing, transparency, error

The transparent texture
[image]

Rendering result
[image]

Material setup

```
ImageTexture [Color] ------- TransparentBSDF --------|
                |                                    |---- MixShader-----SurfaceOutput
                |---------------DiffuseBSDF----------|      [Frac]
             [Alpha]-------------------------------------------|
```

It seems the dark edges come from nowhere...

Comment: That way the fog turns into air and the air turns into fog, but the dark edges still exist. btw, I used gimp's eraser to clean up the boundary so that they appear more natural. Was I doing it right? Will the eraser remove the alpha value as well? But the strange thing is this image still appear to be transparent when I open it in photo viewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch the order for diffuse and transparent

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out. I shouldn't plug the color output to the input of the transparent BSDF